# Make not editable pdf using mPDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm creating pdf files with following code:

```
session_start();
    $fileID = $_SESSION['fileID'];
    $yourHtml = "$fileID.html";
    $mpdf=new mPDF('', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('main.css'),1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents($yourHtml)); 
    $mpdf->Output("$fileID.pdf", 'F');
```

But pdf file created on this way I can edit using applications for vector graphics like Illustrator. How can I make pdf which is not editable.

Comment: You can't really. There's always a way to alter file contents.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Only if you set the user password it works as expected - and that was not the idea. There seem to be a bug in SetProtection(). Compared the sourcecode (v5.6) with the documentation, but no differences or "secrets". It simply doesnt work :(